# Access to HTTP response in Ext.data.Model.save() callbacks using REST proxy

Tags: validation, rest, extjs, extjs4.1

I successfully implemented client editors and a server side API.

Now I'm adding more validation at the server side, and besides returning the proper HTTP code (200 for OK, 4xx for other uses, 500 for errors, etc.) I want to return a list of validations that failed after the submission generated by Model.save().

I run it this way:

```
myModel.save({
  success: function (a, operation, c) {...},
  failure: function (a, operation, c) {...}
});
```

But if there was a failure, the operation object only have the response status and its statusText, all through

```
operation.error.status // i.e. 409
operation.error.statusText // "Conflict"
```

But server side a detail of the failing validations (mostly domain level ones) are being added to the response.

Is there a way I can get what the server sent as the body of the HTTP response to the PUT/POST submission?

Do I have to return it using a particular JSON structure?

EDIT:
I'm now returning this as the body of the HTTP Response (with code 4xx):

```
{
 data: {/* the record serialized */},
 success: false, // or true if everything went ok
 message: "This failed because X and Y."
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Although you have been very descriptive, the question is not very clear to me. 1) It is unclear whether or not 'server side details (?) of the failing validations are being added to the response' does this work as expected? 2) Is the server response in your control? 3) Are you aware of json_encode possibility? 4) have you looked at the restful example under the /examples folder?

Comment: 1) Yes, the failing validation details are in the response 2) I have the server in my control 3) Everything is JSON encoded in a JS object with properties data, message and success (see edit in question) 4) I looked at it, and the response is the same.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand correctly you just want to inspect what you return from the server, is that correct? If such is the case could you just let me know how you send your requests (Direct / Ajax) and whether you need a global response handler or one that is unique per request.

Comment: I evaluate mymodel.save() which internally uses a XHR to send the message to the server, if the code is 2xx it evaluates the success handler, if not it evaluates failure handler. Both showed in my code above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason Ext is not attaching the response content to the error object, but it triggers an `exception` event if there is a failure.

So what we did was to handle the  `"exception"` event of the model's proxy, and then we will have access to the XHR response, being able to do whatever we want with it.

```
myModel.getProxy().on('exception', this.onProxyException, this);
```

The handler is as follows:

```
onProxyException : function (proxy, response, operation) {
    var errors;
    errors = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText).message;
    /* Whatever is needed with the errors */
}
```

In this example we asume the errors come in JSON format, they could be a simple text string, which wouldn't require the use of `decode()`.

Comment: Sencha Touch has the same problem with save() and the proposed solution works just fine.

Answer (score 3):

According to this blog:
http://code.tonytuan.org/2013/07/extjs-get-server-response-in-modelsave.html

You can write code like this:

```
model.save({
    success: function (record, operation) {
    // json response from server         
    console.log(operation.response);                  
    },
    failure: function (record, operation) {
        // undefined
        console.log(operation.response); 
        // json response from server
        console.log(operation.request.scope.reader.jsonData);
    }
});
```

Comment: Upvoted for usefulness in a situation where I needed that response data in an existing failure callback that couldn't feasibly be moved.

Answer (score 0):

1. in reader block add: `messageProperty: 'message'`
2. from server return: `success:false, message: 'error test'`
3. from `failure` get error:

   ```
   failure: function (records, operation) {
       Ext.Msg.alert('error', operation.error);
   }
   ```